# Theory of Automata : Context Free Grammar

Tags: automata

Please help me in making a CFG for this language.

`a^i b^j c^k where i<j+k`

I am fed up of trying this but not able to complete it.

Comment: Can you add one (or more!) attempts you've made? It'll help folks know where you're struggling and how to help you.

Comment: I have done this   S-> 0S1/0S2/1S/S2/1/2 but thing is that I am not getting how to force order in this cfg so that a comes before b and b comes before c

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best suited for CS Stack Exchange.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the [Computer Science StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) as it seems to be about programming theory. Remember to read [their question requirements](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
S -> Ac | Bb
A -> Ac | aAc | B
B -> Bb | aBb | ε
```

You "force order" by first generating as many **c**s as you need before moving on to **b**s.